# For loop character

Tags: java, for-loop, char, character

I am facing a problem. When I type a name such as: 'david'. It terminates successfully but when I enter a name as 'David', it shows an error. Do you guys have any idea/solution for this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        String name;
        int length;
        char alpha;
        boolean status = true;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter name : ");
            name = sc.nextLine();
            length = name.length();

            for (int count = 0; count < length; count++) {
                alpha = name.charAt(count);

                if (alpha < 'a' || alpha > 'z')
                    System.out.print("Error");
                status = (true);
            }


        } while (status == false);

    }
}
```

Comment: Computers recognize the difference between lower and upper case, much like most humans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check, if a character is not a letter, you can use-

```
if(!Character.isLetter(alpha))
    System.out.print("Error");
status = true;
....
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You had made a check for

```
 if(alpha < 'a' || alpha > 'z' )
            System.out.print("Error");
            status = (true);
 }
```

and when you entered 'David'where 'D' is capital then it returns false with your condidtion

Value of
 
a      97 
z     122
D      68

Which clearly shows that D(68) is < a (97)

Comment: DO NOT mislead the OP please. This has nothing to do with ASCII. Please point to the Unicode code points list instead.